# Getting the dimension of a Vector in Math.NET

Tags: vector, math.net, mathnet-numerics

If I was given a Vector in Math.NET, how can I check the number of dimensions that it has? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `Count` property.

If I remember correctly, the property was named Count instead of Length or Dimensions to be consistent with `RowCount` and `ColumnCount` in matrices.

Comment: Ah.. I saw the Count property in the documentation, but it had no description and the name was pretty ambiguous. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, the inline docs of the Count property was useless; I've just [changed it](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Vector%601.htm#Count) so at least it mentions length and number of dimensions.